# bash: cd: No such file or directory being returned but directory exists

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to run the following code

```
#!/bin/bash

source="/Users/9001128.ELOCAL/Downloads"
destination="/Users/Public/Documents"
days="+1"

destination=$(cd -- "$destination" && pwd) # make it an absolute path
cd -- "$source" &&
find . -type f -mtime +1 -atime +1 -exec sh -c '
  mkdir -p "$0/${1%/*}"
  mv "$1" "$0/$1"
' "$destination" {} \;

destination=$(cd -- "$destination" && pwd) # make it an absolute path
cd -- "$source" &&
find . -type f -mtime +1 -atime +1 -exec sh -c '
  for x do
    mkdir -p "$0/${x%/*}"
    mv "$x" "$0/$x"
  done
' "$destination" {} +

autoload -U zmv
mkdir_mv () {
  mkdir -p -- $3:h
  mv -- $2 $3
}
zmv -Qw -p mkdir_mv $source/'**/*(.m-'$days')' '$destination/$1$2'
```

Its function is to move the files to a new directory and maintain the directory structure, as in the example:
/Users/Public/Documents/file.txt

after moving to backup it would look like this:
backup/Users/Public/Documents/file.txt

Keeping the whole structure.

But when I run the script, I get the following message in the shell:

```
bash: cd: /Users/Public/Documents: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong so that the script doesn't work?

Comment: Does the directory exists? Try running the script under `set -xv` to see what's going on.

Comment: `make it an absolute path` should use the `realpath` command

Comment: How do I do that? @stark